# Is there a way to get all WorkItemType Available Columns Programmatically?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I think I may have to pull the Project and the Project Type and then For each `WorkItemType` pull the Available Columns?

I thought I could do it by pulling all the values from the property like this:

```
WorkItem WI;

Type myType = WI.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object propValue = prop.GetValue(myObject, null);
}
```

But I don't think that's the right way to do it. Is there way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking about board columns(eg. custom kanban board columns/swimlanes) or do you just want a list of all the fields (eg. System.Title) for each Work Item in a Team Project?

Comment: I'm obviously not super familiar with this, but I found that some WorkItemTypes don't have Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate, so basically I want to be able to see the available columns for each time, especially ones like Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a list of all the fields  for all type of work item.

You can list the work item type fields that are defined for a team project collection(the same with project) by using the following **witadmin** command which located in the Common7/IDE folder of your Visual Studio installation:

```
witadmin listfields /collection:http://my.tfs.server/MyCollection
```

Detail description of this command you can refer here: [Manage work item fields [witadmin]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236909.aspx)

Moreover, there is a Work item field index from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/guidance/work-item-field-index). This reference includes all fields defined within the core system processes/process templates: Agile, Scrum, and CMMI.

[image]